# How can I trap errors for an application that is tightly coupled with IIS?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, error-logging

We have an unsupported application that relies on IIS however intermittently brings out the website it is integrated with. I have looked at the logs and there is nothing in the logs to indicate what the issue could be as the logs only have GET verbs. I have also looked at the event viewer and there are no error logged in there either.

The application runs off a Windows 2008 server.

Is there a freely available application we can have running in the background that will listen  to or is aware of the application running and traps the error when it crashes? The unsupported application is a bespoke implementation for which we don't have code for and the developer is no longer contactable.

Comment: getting memory dump on crash is easy, doing anything with it without the code to be able to match memory locations to variable, method, class, function... names is the real problem. Visual studio has an on demand debugger that kicks in when windows detects a crash, but without debugging symbols or source code it's not often very useful.

Comment: @ewanm89 - I was afraid that was going to be the case. Any way I can get more output from IIS as I believe a request of some sort that the application is not designed to handled is being made?

Comment: What do you mean by "however intermittently brings out the website it is integrated with"?  How does it "rely" on IIS, is it a Web App?  How is it 'crashing' (stops, or just to busy to answer)? What's actually crashing (the Application, the IIS App Pool, IIS itself?

Comment: @techie007 - Yes it is an application that has a website within IIS. When it crashes, it stops the website in question. Crashing was probably not the right word to use. It stops the website and the application stops working. The IIS app pool for the application also stops. IIS does not stop itself. The only way to bring the application up again is to start the application pool and website.

Comment: Is it running in it's own App Pool, and is that App Pool setup to be a web garden?

Comment: @techie007 - Yes it is running in its own application pool. What is a web garden?

Comment: It's like a small Web Farm, only on one web server ([some info](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/on-web-gardens-aspnet-and-iis-60/)).  Basically it allows IIS to use more than one web serving process to serve one session.  One of the common gotchas is if you are using server-side InProcess session variables in your web app.  These are a no-no in a garden or farm setup because they can't/won't be shared between the worker processes, so the variables can/will be lost (or disjointed) between responses.

Comment: The Web App has to be configured/designed for a web garden, and sometimes IIS seems to like to turn it on by default.  If it's not designed for it, all kinds of strange things can happen in the app. :)